# How can I translate the LOOKUP function from Excel to Access?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have two tables:

One where I have a range of values and a description that I want my query to deliver.

| min val | max val | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | This client has 0 to a 100 days |
| 101 | 500 | This client has 101 to a 500 days |

And table 2, which has the id of the client and a number of days:

| ID | # DAYS |
| --- | --- |
| id0005 | 50 |
| id0007 | 499 |

When I use Excel I solve this problem using a LOOKUP function, however, the database is really big and I need to translate this to Access. So far I have been using an IIf function:
i.e. IIf (# DAYS BETWEEN 0 AND 100, "This client has 0 to 100 days", IIf (# DAYS BETWEEN 101 AND 500, "This client has 101 to 500 days", NEXT CASE)

But my table 1 has lots of cases, around 20, so I would like to know if there is an easier way to do this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Consider this expression that can be used in query, textbox, or VBA:

```
DLookup("Description", "Table1", [# Days] & " BETWEEN [min val] AND [max val]")
```

Domain aggregate functions can cause slow performance in query with very large dataset. Unfortunately, alternative is probably not better:

```
SELECT Table2.ID, Table2.[# Days], Description
FROM Table2, Table1
WHERE Table2.[# Days] Between Table1.[min val] And Table1.[max val];
```

Lack of a JOIN clause employs a Cartesian relationship so every record of each table associates with every record of other table. If each table has 1,000 records the dataset will be 1,000,000 records. WHERE clause limits the output.

Review this explanation of non-equijoin issue. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/access-cookbook/0596000847/ch01s10.html

Strongly advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables on >= and <=, although I've no idea what's going on behind the scenes - whether it creates a cartesian join first or not, and whether it's faster than the SQL that @June7 provided.

```
SELECT  ID, Description 
FROM    Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.[# Days]>=Table1.[min val] AND  
                                   Table2.[# Days]<=Table1.[max val]
```

This query can't be represented in the design view, only in SQL view.

The LEFT JOIN ensures you get everything back from Table2.  Description will remain NULL where # Days is outside the ranges given in Table1.

Comment: And I was just about to amend my answer to include this. As noted, the JOIN ON must be typed in SQL View, cannot build in Design View.

Comment: Attempt to switch to Design View will generate errors and not display JOIN. However, I noted that the errors will not always appear on subsequent attempts. So the query will open to Design View, just won't show any JOIN links. Switch back to SQL View and the syntax is still intact. Although if saved from Design View the JOIN ON is lost. I tested with 2 records in each table. The errors popped up 4 times.